# Freelancing as a Part time or Full time?

Tags: freelance-websites

I wish to do freelancing in Upwork as a part-time, Is it worth it or is it nothing worth like a full-time career?

Answer (score 3):

All of this depends on your skills and dedication, and the amount of time that you can dedicate.
You can work both as a part-time as well as full-time freelancer on Upwork. All you need to do is start by keeping prices low and polish your skills continuously. Once you grab enough clients you can make it as a full-time career.
Many freelancers on Upwork are working as a full-time freelancers, and they are earning more than enough.

Answer (score 3):

**It is worth trying!**

The corporate culture with a boss and a deadline is very frustrating when company is paying you in penny

In Freelancing the most difficult job is to find clients when you are a beginner. But once you have build our portfolio with good clients then this freelancing becomes fun todo job. Also then there would be no boss, you can work anytime and anywhere you want this makes you a person with more freedom

So my suggestion is start with part-time. First you will face difficulties but later if you like you can start with full-time by quitting your job

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your needs. The popular opinion about freelancing is to earn extra money ( "not a real job, use for extra money" ). However, see this article of Forbes magazine could change that bad opinion about freelancing:

> ["Survey: For Many, Freelancing Pays Better Than Traditional Jobs](https://www.forbes.com/sites/elainepofeldt/2015/10/04/survey-for-many-freelancing-pays-better-than-traditional-jobs/?sh=57534ede3d1a)

- The line between freelancers and traditional workers has blurred.
  Among the freelancers surveyed, 25% have full-time businesses, 50%
  freelance part-time, 20% have full-time jobs and earn extra money from freelancing and the remainder checked the “other” category. “For
  a lot of these folks, it is additional income.
- Freelancers are spending more hours at their businesses. Although many freelancers in the survey are running their businesses part-time, the number of hours they are investing is climbing. Last year they averaged 15 hours a week. Now it’s nearly 19 hours a week. That is a substantial leap. And given that some of the freelancers surveyed are moonlighters, it could indicate that more American workers are deciding that they will be better off directing their discretionary effort to their own business than to their primary job.

other good stats:

[Upwork Freelancer earning statistics‍:](https://www.upwork.com/resources/how-much-do-freelancers-make)

- Upwork’s past industry research has shown that 60% of freelancers who left a full-time job to become freelancers make more money than they did in their previous jobs.
- According to 2020 freelancer research data, freelancers in the United States earn an average hourly rate of $20.
- Freelancers working in web/mobile development, marketing, legal, accounting, and other skilled services earn an even higher $28/hour average wage. At $28/hour, these freelancers are making more than 70% of all workers in the United States.

I am working now full-time but I would like my freelance work to be part-time or sporadic contracts, like a digital nomad, this would give me some time to have an office job or develop my career.

Answer (score 1):

It's depends upon your preference and needs some people's like Freelancing for earning extra money; On the other hand some do Freelancing full time and it's also depends on your skills

Comment: Welcome to Freelancing! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to back it with references to credible sources and/or academic research. Unbacked posts attract downvotes and disputes.